# Chrome doesn't ask for proxy authentication but Firefox does

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, proxy, http-proxy

I am trying to connect to my college wifi using LAN Cable. When i connect my laptop to cable and change the proxy settings, two things happen:-

1. Firefox asks for Username and password. After providing username and password, I am able to surf the internet on firefox.
2. But Chrome, neither asks for authentication, nor am I able to surf the internet using chrome.

What can be possible reasons for this and how to fix this ? I have tried reading articles related to proxy settings,LAN etc, but I am not able to solve this issue.